# Computing Mahalanobis Distance Component Wise

Tags: python, performance, distance

I have 60000 vectors of 784 dimensions. This data has 10 classes.

I must evaluate a function that takes out one dimension and computes the distance metric again. This function is computing the distance of each vector to it's classes' mean. In code:

```
def objectiveFunc(self, X, y, indices):

    subX = np.array([X[:,i] for i in indices]).T
    d = np.zeros((10,1))
    for n in range(10):
        C = subX[np.where(y == n)]
        u = np.mean(C, axis = 0)
        Sinv = pinv(covariance(C))
        d[n] = np.mean(np.apply_along_axis(mahalanobis, axis = 1, arr=C, v=u, VI=Sinv))
```

where indices are fed in with one index removed during each iteration.

As you can imagine, I am computing a lot of individual components during the computation for Mahalanobis distance. Is there a way for me to store all the 784 component distances?

Alternatively, what's the fastest way to compute Mahalanobis distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all and to make it easier to understand, this is the Mahalanobis Distance formula:

[image: Mahalanobis]

So, to compute the mahalanobis distance for each element according to its class, we can do:

```
X_train=X_train.reshape(-1,784)

def mahalanobis(element,classe):
    part=np.where(y_train==classe)[0]
    ave=np.mean(X_train[part])
    distance_example=np.sqrt(((np.mean(X_train[part[[element]]])-ave)**2)/np.var(X_train[part]))
    return distance_example

mahalanobis(20,2)    
# Out[91]: 0.13947337027828757
```

Then you can create a `for` statement to calculate all distances. For instance, class `0`:

```
[mahalanobis(i,0) for i in range(0,len(X_train[np.where(y_train==0)[0]]))]
```

Comment: Thank you. That is not a form I've seen before. Can you please provide a link so I can read further? Secondly, Sigma is the variance squared?

Comment: Sigma is Standand Deviation. Sigma squared is Variance. For reference, read the book from Hair:  Multivariate Data Analysis. It has more like a statistical approach, than properly practical Machine Learning.

Comment: I found a PDF of the book online. I couldn't find the above form; I searched for the term mahalanobis.

Comment: How did you come to the assumption that there is no covariance?

Comment: Does `Y` present covariance? It is categorical, 10 classes, you can't calculate `Y` mean with categorical variables as in covariance. Consider for instance the solution for MNIST using K Nearest Neighbor. It's similar to your approach, but it will use centroids of `X` instead of the Mahalanobis mean.

Comment: Y represents the labels in my case. I’m using the mnist dataset. Can you please elaborate on this in your answer? Your answer assumes that the covariances are zero and the components are not correlated, right? My confusion is why is that the case.